# How should I use Parcelable for abstract classes?

Tags: java, android

In my Android application, I basically have one class which implements `Parcelable`, and one of its fields which needs to be read from and written to a `Parcel` is a reference to an abstract class that also implements `Parcelable`.

Here is the abstract class and one of its concrete implementations:

```
public abstract AbstractClass1 implements Parcelable {
}

public class ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractClass1 {
    private ConcreteClass1(Parcel in) {
        this.setSomeData(in.readInt());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ConcreteClass1> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<ConcreteClass1>() {
            public ConcreteClass1 createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new ConcreteClass1 (in);
            }

            public ConcreteClass1[] newArray(int size) {
                return new ConcreteClass1[size];
            }
        };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() { return 0; }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.getSomeData());
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far for the other `Parcelable` class that needs to read and write a reference to `AbstractClass1` into its `Parcel`.  I'm not sure how to make the `CREATOR` work:

```
public Class2 implements Parcelable {
    private int data = 42;
    private AbstractClass1 class1;

    public Class2(AbstractClass1 c) { this.class1 = c; }

    private Class2(Parcel in) {
        this.data = in.readInt();

        // this line is bad since it requires us to know about
        // what concrete class is being set for class1.  This
        // class should only need to be aware of AbstractClass1
        this.class1 = in.readParcelable(ConcreteClass1.class);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Class2> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<Class2>() {
            public Class2 createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Class2(in);
            }

            public Class2[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Class2[size];
            }
        };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() { return 0; }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.data);
        dest.writeInt(this.class1);
    }
}
```

Is there a best practice for how to deal with this abstract class issue with `Parcelable`s?  I understand that `Parcelable` is not meant to be a general purpose tool for serialization, but its seems like this would be an important issue for a lot of applications, and it's vitally necessary to get `Parcelable`s to work in case the user presses the back button then wants to return to the app, as the state of the app needs to be saved.  I special `CREATOR` on `AbstractClass1` wouldn't work either since this class shouldn't know about the concrete implementations.  Should it be some sort of factory pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `writeParcelable(Parcelable, int)` writes the name of the appropriate non-abstract class to the `Parcel` (as well as the data you write in the `writeToParcel` method).

The reverse of this is `readParcelable(null)`. `readParcelable` first reads the name of the class back so is then able to get the right `Creator` object from that class before invoking the `Creator`'s `createFromParcel` method.

The argument for `readParcelable` is not a `Class` but a `ClassLoader`. If you pass `null` the default `ClassLoader` is used.

Comment: Oops, looks like I confused `ClassLoader` for `Class`.  Thanks for your help!